# application created by qt creator can not get LD_LIBRARY_PATH on DEBIAN 7.8.0 x86

Tags: qt, debian, environment-variables, shared-libraries

I encountered a question about LD_LIBRARY_PATH on debian,any help will be appreciated!
I have a application created by Qt Creator3.5.1(opensource) based on Qt5.5.1(GCC 4.9.1, 32bit) running on debian 7.8,and the question is:

- The application needs some .so files in the
  path"/opt/scan/bin/lib",and I add it to /etc/ld.so.conf followed by
  the command "ldconfig"
- when I run the application in the shell (like ./app),it works fine,but if I
  double click on the icon(executable file ) it can not find those .so files
- I wrote some code to test if the program get the environment variable,and show it using an information window,results show that when run in shell it can get and use LD_LIBRARY_PATH,but running by mouse click it even can not get the environment( path is NULL):

  char *path;

  path = getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH");

  QMessageBox::information(NULL,"tip",path);
- then, I use `system("export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/scan/bin/lib")` in
  the `main()`function, but it changes nothing.

when debugging in qt creator,I configured `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/scan/bin` 
in`projects->build&run->build->build environment` and also the `run environment` through similar way,if not, it will work like double click the executable file,can not find the .so file

I'm new here and English is not my mother tongue, so sorry for the grammar and spelling(I've tried), hoping for help,thanks!

---

I also add `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/san/bin/lib`and `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in `/etc/profile`

Comment: Did you set application path in your .desktop file?

Comment: no，I will try it，thank you.but I don't understand it, can you explain it?

Comment: Your "icon", if I understand correctly, is a file with `.desktop` extension. Edit it manually and add line `Path=/path/to/your/app`.

Comment: @MichaelO. May be I haven't explain my question clearly.the icon I mean is the executable file.

Comment: Which DE you use? Try to launch your file manager from console (`dolphin`, `nautilus`, `thunar`) and see console output when you launch your app.

Comment: DE?is gnome a DE?

Comment: @MichaelO. Launch from shell(terminal) the app works fine

Comment: OK. You have gnome, so type in console `nautilus`, launch your app from nautilus by double clicking, and see what is happening in console.

Comment: @MichaelO. Thanks for your help,but maybe I need more. Does console mean terminal? I typed nautilus in terminal,and it just open a file manager system for me,I double clicked the executable file and nothing printed in the terminal,the app still can not find.so files. I know it can not find theses.so files because I wrote some code to out put this errors by information window